# Reference for Leibnitz formula for ‘infinitesimal calculus’?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

Someone knows where Leibnitz wrote his formula for ‘infinitesimal calculus’ (I need a reference and cannot find it, easily at least, on the web).

Thanks.

Comment: What formula? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_(disambiguation)

Answer (score 1):

OK, Leibnitz and Wallis correspondences, in mathematische schriften. (Found!)

Thanks everyone.